# Footer Social icons won't align

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to arrange my Social icons so that they will be placed on the same level as some text on in the footer. I will provide a [Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKppj.png) of the footer I have so far as well as the html and css code I have made so far. I wanted to figure out if i need to put the social icons into another div so that I can control the position that way, or would i need to utilize position element here?

```css
footer {
  background: #212529;
  color: white;
  width: calc(100% - 80px);
  margin-left: 80px;
  margin-right: -15px;
}

footer a {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
}

footer a:hover {
  color: #FA944B;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.copy {
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-top: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
}

.footer-middle {
  padding-top: 2em;
  color: white;
}


/* Footer social icons */

ul.social-network {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
  margin-left: 0 !important;
  padding: 0;
}

ul.social-network li {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0 5px;
}

.social-network a.icoFacebook:hover {
  background-color: #3B5998;
}

.social-network a.icoLinkedin:hover {
  background-color: #007bb7;
}

.social-network a.icoFacebook:hover i,
.social-network a.icoLinkedin:hover i {
  color: #fff;
}

.social-network a.socialIcon:hover,
.socialHoverClass {
  color: #44BCDD;
}

.social-circle li a {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.social-circle li i {
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.social-circle li a:hover i,
.triggeredHover {
  -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -ms--transform: rotate(360deg);
  transform: rotate(360deg);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

.social-circle i {
  color: #595959;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.8s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.8s;
  -o-transition: all 0.8s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.8s;
  transition: all 0.8s;
}

.social-network a {
  background-color: #F9F9F9;
}
```

```html
<footer class="mainfooter" role="contentinfo">
  <div class="footer-middle">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
          <!--Column1-->
          <div class="footer-pad">
            <h4>ACTIVITÉS</h4>
            <ul class="list-styled">
              <li>
                <a href="#"></a>Rafting</li>
              <li><a href="#">Kayak</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Parachute</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Soufflerie</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Saut élastique</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
          <!--Column1-->
          <div class="footer-pad">
            <h4>INFORMATIONS</h4>
            <ul class="list-unstyled">
              <li><a href="#">Mentions légales</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">À Propos de nous</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">CGV</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">CGU</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
          <!--Column1-->
          <div class="footer-pad">
            <h4>OFFRES</h4>
            <ul class="list-unstyled">
              <li><a href="#">Solo</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Groupe</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Famille</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
          <!--Column1-->
          <div class="footer-pad">
            <h4>PARTENAIRES</h4>
            <ul class="list-unstyled">
              <li><a href="#">Nos Partenaires</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Devenir Partenaire</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3">
          <ul class="social-network social-circle">
            <li><a href="#" class="icoFacebook" title="Facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="icoYoutube" title="Youtube"><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="icoTwitter" title="Twitter"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="icoInstagram" title="Instagram"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
          </ul>
          <h4>Suivez-Nous</h4>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 copy">
          <p class="text-center">&copy; Copyright 2018 - Company Name. All rights reserved.</p>
        </div>
      </div>


    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: would you more clear what are try to achieve ?

Comment: In the photo that i provided the social icons are resting on top of "Suivez Nous". I want it to be on the same line as the text, just to the right side of it :).

Comment: give `d-flex` with `.col` class and put  `<h4>` first then `ul`...

Comment: do you want this [codepen](https://codepen.io/noor007/pen/GRqJVKd)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add CSS to `<h4>Suivez-Nous</h4>` `h4{ display:inline }"`and change the order

Answer (score 0):

You can add `d-flex` class to your `.col-md-3` element and thus `<h4>` element and social icons will be in a row.

P.S. I have changed `.col-md-3` to `.col-md-6`, cause in `.col-md-3` icons start to wrap onto multiple lines

```
<div class="col-md-6 d-flex">
          <h4>Suivez-Nous</h4>
        
          <ul class="social-network social-circle">
            <li><a href="#" class="icoFacebook" title="Facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="icoYoutube" title="Youtube"><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="icoTwitter" title="Twitter"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="icoInstagram" title="Instagram"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
          </ul>
          
        </div>
```

Full code: https://jsfiddle.net/8pL49rs7/